# how to pause and resume wxThread with button event

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to fill wxListCtrl with the database, and for this I'm using `wxThread` concept. I want to add two buttons in the frame, for pause and resume thread. How can this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution - I was trying to pause and resume thread with the button event. For this

1. Take two buttons `wxButton *stop, *resume`
2. Create two button events:

   ```
   void onstopbuttonclick(wxCommandEvent & event);
   void onresumebuttonclick(wxCommandEvent & event);
   ```
3. At stop button event, write:

   ```
   void login::onstopbuttonclick(wxCommandEvent& evt)
   {
       temper->Pause();//temper is object of thread class      
   }
   ```
4. At resume button event, write:

   ```
   void login::onresumebuttonclick(wxCommandEvent& evt)
   {
       temper->Resume();
   }
   ```
5. Write finally in Entry() method:

   ```
   if(TestDestroy())                                                   
   {
       return NULL;
   }
   ```

   Write this before your thread code, when you click stop button this condition will be true that time and thread will not perform any work that time.